# Gridview hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My first Page :

### .aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
       BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
       CssClass="grdDataGrid" Height="102px" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"> 
   <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" /> <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
   <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
   <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
   <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> 
</asp:GridView>
```

### code behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var firstCell = e.Row.Cells[0];
        firstCell.Controls.Clear();
        firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = "ser_job_status1.aspx?Complaint_No = " + firstCell.Text, Text = firstCell.Text, Target = "_blank" });
        Session["Complaint_No"] = firstCell.Text;
        //////Session["Complaint_No"] = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[HyperLink(NavigateUrl)].Value.ToString();

      }
 }
GridView1.DataBind();
```

My second page :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
   string strComplaintNo = Convert.ToString(Session["Complaint_No"]);
   TextBox51.Text = strComplaintNo;
}
```

My Question is since i have use Hyperlink before Binding Datasource to Gridview my firstCell.
Text value holds last fetched data.
 So if i click on that link my sessoin get the value of firstCell.
Text which is inturn last fetched value.. But my requirement is to fetch the hyperlinked value.. 
can anyone help me to solve this issue
I have used C# as my code behind...

Comment: where do you want to use this value?

Answer (score 1):

give each hyperlink an id in each row depnds on row index,

```
HyperLink HLLink = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("HyperLink"+e.RowIndex) as  HyperLink;

Session["Complaint_No"]=HLLink.NavigateURL.ValueToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

 As you are sending value through the query string to the next page.
You can set the value there.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strComplaintNo = Request.QueryString.Get("Complaint_No");
    Session["Complaint_No"]=strComplaintNo ;
    TextBox51.Text = strComplaintNo ;
}
```

### Edit 1

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Request No.">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="EditHyperLink1" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl='<%#"ser_job_status1.aspx?reqid=" + Eval("ReqId") %>'
            Text='<%# Eval("ReqId") %>' >
       <!--change the column name "ReqId"-->
       </asp:HyperLink>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And on your **ser_job_status1.aspx** page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strComplaintNo = Request.QueryString.Get("reqid");
    //call your method on the basis of strComplaintNo
   // Session["Complaint_No"]=strComplaintNo ;
    //TextBox51.Text = strComplaintNo ;
}
```

Comment: Mr.Shekhar....same thing i did with session.. This works... my problem is fetching value from first page itself an issue... since rowdatabound event fetches all data including hyperlink details and finally it is binded to gridview so the last fetched value is passed as session value...

Comment: @Sathya that's ok but what do you want to do the session values?

Comment: Taking that value as an input other fields in the second page will be populated.. For ex: Taking complaint no as an input i have to populate complaint date, status etc.

Comment: I don't understand why to use session if you can get there from the query string.

Comment: I am updating my example with hyper link approach

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White"   BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"CssClass="grdDataGrid" Height="102px" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                            <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" /><PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" /><SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /<HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> </asp:GridView>

Comment: This is my Gridview.. Since Autogeneretad = true... i am not able to use Hyperlink Field or 
template field

Comment: What happen when you click on the hyperlink of you `gridview`. Does it goes to `ser_job_status1.aspx`?

Comment: ya it goes to ser_job_status1.aspx page

Comment: and you are **getting right value** the value in the query string?

Comment: No the complaint no which is bound finally to the gridiew that is passed as Query string to second page...